# Updating several records at once using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, records

I want to create a list of records with checkboxes on the left side....kinda like the inbox in Gmail.  Then if a user selects some or all of these checkboxes, then the selected record(s) can be updated (only one field will be updated BTW), possibly by clicking a button.

I'm stuck on how to do this though....ideas?

**Display Code**

```
{% for issue in issues %}
   <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
      <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="{{ issue.id }}" /></td>
      <td>{{ issue.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ issue.type }}</td>
      <td>{{ issue.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ issue.date_time_added|date:"d, M Y" }}</td>
      <td>{{ issue.added_by }}</td>
      <td>{{ issue.assigned_to }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Use the queryset `update()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

```
id_list = list_of_ids_from_checkboxes
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).update(myattribute=True)
```

Your display HTML is missing a `name` value for the checkboxes. If you just have a single name across all checkboxes, then the list of IDs will be passed into a single POST variable, which you can get straight from `request.POST` (assuming you're submitting your form as a post, which you should be):

```
id_list = request.POST.getlist('checkboxname')
```

Comment: My main problem is with the checkboxes....sorry I forgot to mention that bit....how do I pass along the selected ids?

Comment: How are you generating the checkboxes?

Comment: The update() method is very useful, just make sure that you are aware of an important caveat! If you have custom save() method on your affected model(s) and/or pre_save / post_save signal handlers, those will not get called.