# Update several records at once using Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-templates

I want to know a way on how to update the data once is edited from the input boxes all with one click. I found this post on how to do it with checkboxes:
[Updating several records at once using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743802/updating-several-records-at-once-using-django)
 but I'm not sure how to do it for input boxes.

here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Local</th>
              <th>line</th>
              <th>rack</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for linea in lineas_de_reporte %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ linea.local }}</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="case-opened" value="{{ linea.rack }}" id="caseOpened"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="case-opened" value="{{ linea.line }}" id="caseOpened"/></td>

          </tr>
         {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
```

Here is how it looks:
[image]

**Is there a way bu just sending all the values (by id) to a function in a list using Django?**

EDIT:

forms.py

```
class TVSForm(forms.Form):
    rack = forms.CharField()
    line = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
def search_folio(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = FolioSearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        folio_number = request.POST.get('folio_number', '')
        folio = 'FOLIO' + str(folio_number)
        folio_query = InventoryFolioManagement.objects.filter(folio=folio)
        context = {
            'lineas_de_reporte': folio_query,
            'folio': ' | ' + folio
        }
        return render(request, 'inv-search-folio.html', context)
else:
    form = FolioSearchForm()

if request.GET.get('rack'):
    # ... this means that user clicked on the submit button
    # get the id of linea
    linea_id = request.GET.get('rack-id')
    new_case = request.GET.get('rack')
    # fetch object from db, based on that id (aka pk)
    linea = TechnicalValidationSystem.objects.get(id=linea_id)
    # change its attribute to True
    linea.case_opened = new_case
    # update db with the new value
    linea.save(update_fields=['rack'])

return render(request, 'inv-search-folio.html')
```

Comment: do you already have a form in place?

Comment: I did something similar but by updating every field, and I did added a form like this:

Comment: <form action="{% url 'tvs' %}" method="GET">
                                            <td><input type="text" name="case-opened" value="{{ linea.rack }}" id="caseOpened"/></td>
                                            </form>

Comment: sorry I meant a django Form, python code to update your records.

Comment: let me edit my question and add forms.py

Comment: I still dont have a code to update them, but I have an idea

Comment: You may want to look into [Model Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) for handling multiple of the same object in one form

Comment: @DRC I will just update my python logic, give a me sec

Comment: That code is similar to the one I use to update one field at a time, I need to modify all the data, then updated by just one click

Comment: Any ideas? :( ...