# Updating a group of Django objects in one click

Tags: django, post, checkbox, request

I have a Message model with an 'unread' field set to default=True:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to be able to select a group of these objects at once and alter their unread status on click. Each of them are currently being displayed with a checkbox alongside, wrapped inside a form:

```
<form action="{% url 'users:read_message' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Mark as read</button>

    {% for msg in messages %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="message" value="{{ msg.id }}">
        <p>{{ msg.message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

And here is the view:

```
def message_unread(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_messages = request.POST.getlist('message')
        Message.objects.filter(id__in=selected_messages).update(unread=True)
        return redirect('users:messages')
    return redirect('users:my_profile')
```

This is working, however I will also need a second form in order to change the status back to unread=False, and ideally a third to be able to delete them. Since HTML forbids the use of nested forms, how can I achieve this without displaying three loops of messages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating several records at once using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743802/updating-several-records-at-once-using-django)

Comment: Btw, your inputs are outside the `<form>` which results the `POST` to become empty.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, although has lead me to a new problem. I didn't mention the other forms I would need earlier in order to save space, but it is necessary to include them now. Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using three submit buttons on the form each containing the `formaction` attribute